# How to contribute to homebrew-cask using GitHub?

Tags: github, homebrew, homebrew-cask

The quotation below is the instruction to contribute to brew-cask. However, I could not understand the sentence: `github_user='<my-github-username>'`, I do not know whether should I input `<>`, and what is the `github_user`?

There is one email address, two names for one single GitHub account. What is more, when I input the last sentence: `cask-repair --pull origin --push $github_user $outdated_cask`. There is 2 errors: `the requested upstream branch 'Andy1984' does not exist`, and

```
Error creating pull request: Unprocessable Entity (HTTP 422)
Invalid value for "head"
```

and the result is `There was an error submitting the pull request. Have you forked the repo and made sure the pull and push remotes exist?` I am quite sure I followed the instructions. What is wrong?

```
# install and setup script - only needed once
brew install vitorgalvao/tiny-scripts/cask-repair
cask-repair --help

# fork homebrew-cask to your account - only needed once
cd "$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/Casks"
hub fork

# use to update <outdated_cask>
outdated_cask='<the-cask-i-want-to-update>'
github_user='<my-github-username>'
cd "$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/Casks"

cask-repair --pull origin --push $github_user $outdated_cask
```

Comment: `github_user='<my-github-username>'` means if your github user name is `johndoe`, you replace it with `github_user=johndoe`. `github_user` is the name of your github account. If you don't remember you can look it up on your profile page on github.

Comment: Yes, I did as you said, but still:'the requested upstream branch 'Andy1984' does not exist'

Comment: But you did set the `outdated_cask` variable to the name of the cask you want to update, right?

Comment: Yes, I set. I doubt the problem is about `github_user`, because I set `github_user` as `Andy1984`, and it always says  `the requested upstream branch 'Andy1984' does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you can also use a script to push new version of an existing cask.

Check: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#updating-a-cask

```
# install and setup script - only needed once
brew install vitorgalvao/tiny-scripts/cask-repair
cask-repair --help

# use to update <outdated_cask>
cask-repair <outdated_cask>
```